# How to delete duplicate rows that comply with a condition in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

How could I delete the duplicate names that have an amount = 0?

```
Table1
    +------+------+--------------------+--------+
| t_id | p_id |         name       | amount |
+------+------+--------------------+--------+
|    1 |    1 | 6 cans of lemonade |      0 |
|    1 |    1 | 6 cans of lemonade |      1 |
|    1 |    2 | Pack of rice       |      0 |
|    1 |    2 | Roast chicken      |      1 |
|    1 |    2 | Roast chicken      |      0 |
|    1 |    3 | Pack of butter     |      0 |
|    1 |    3 | Pack of butter     |      1 |
|    1 |    3 | Toast bread        |      0 |
|    1 |    3 | Toast bread        |      1 |
|    1 |    4 | 2l of milk         |      0 |
|    1 |    4 | 2l of milk         |      2 |
|    1 |    4 | 3kg sugar          |      0 |
|    1 |    4 | 3kg sugar          |      1 |
|    1 |    4 | Banana             |      0 |
|    1 |    4 | Banana             |      3 |
+------+------+--------------------+--------+
```

At the same time, I want to leave those that do not have a duplicate.

So I would end up with something like this:

```
Table2
+------+------+--------------------+--------+
| t_id | p_id |         name       | amount |
+------+------+--------------------+--------+
|    1 |    1 | 6 cans of lemonade |      1 |
|    1 |    2 | Pack of rice       |      0 |
|    1 |    2 | Roast chicken      |      1 |
|    1 |    3 | Pack of butter     |      1 |
|    1 |    3 | Toast bread        |      1 |
|    1 |    4 | 2l of milk         |      2 |
|    1 |    4 | 3kg sugar          |      1 |
|    1 |    4 | Banana             |      3 |
+------+------+--------------------+--------+
```

Comment: What if there are duplicates with all having amount = 0?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a GROUP BY  and MAX so you get the rows you want to get see select and left join itir . The rest gets deleted

> ```
> SELECT 
> MAX(`t_id`), `p_id`, `name`, MAX(`amount`)
> FROM Table1
> GROUP BY p_id, `name`
> ```
>
> ```
> MAX(`t_id`) | p_id | name               | MAX(`amount`)
> ----------: | ---: | :----------------- | ------------:
>           1 |    1 | 6 cans of lemonade |             1
>           1 |    2 | Pack of rice       |             0
>           1 |    2 | Roast chicken      |             1
>           1 |    3 | Pack of butter     |             1
>           1 |    3 | Toast bread        |             1
>           1 |    4 | 2l of milk         |             2
>           1 |    4 | 3kg sugar          |             1
>           1 |    4 | Banana             |             3
> ```

> ```
> DELETE t1.* FROM Table1 t1 LEFT JOIN (SELECT 
> MAX(`t_id`) mid, `p_id`, `name`, MAX(`amount`) maxamount
> FROM Table1 
> GROUP BY p_id, `name`) t2 ON t1.`t_id` = t2.mid AND t1.`p_id` = t2.`p_id` 
> AND  t1.`name` = t2.`name` AND t1.`amount` = t2.maxamount 
> WHERE t2.`mid` IS NULL
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM Table1
> ```
>
> ```
> t_id | p_id | name               | amount
> ---: | ---: | :----------------- | -----:
>    1 |    1 | 6 cans of lemonade |      1
>    1 |    2 | Pack of rice       |      0
>    1 |    2 | Roast chicken      |      1
>    1 |    3 | Pack of butter     |      1
>    1 |    3 | Toast bread        |      1
>    1 |    4 | 2l of milk         |      2
>    1 |    4 | 3kg sugar          |      1
>    1 |    4 | Banana             |      3
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e49c3cea61a6b94496370c50359ea363)*

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . I am thinking a `delete` with an aggregation to determine if there is a non-zero amount for the `t_id`/`p_id` pair:

```
delete t
    from t join
         (select t_id, p_id, name, max(amount) as max_amount
          from t
          group by t_id, p_id, name
         ) tt
         using (t_id, p_id, name)
    where amount = 0 and max_amount > 0;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8e3a10fce03dbdf07dc529223050b85f) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to run this more times, until the result of deleted numbers will be 0.

```
DELETE
FROM Table1
WHERE (name, amount) in(

    SELECT t.name, t.minAmount
    FROM (
        SELECT
          *, MIN(amount) as minAmount
        FROM
          Table1
        GROUP BY
          name
        HAVING 
          COUNT(name) > 1
    ) 
    t
)
```

---

Details:
Select those records, which names are more than 1 in the table:

```
        SELECT
          *, MIN(amount) as minAmount
        FROM
          Table1
        GROUP BY
          name
        HAVING 
          COUNT(name) > 1
```

Select names and the minimal amount.

```
    SELECT t.name, t.minAmount
    FROM (
        ...
    )
    t
```

Delete those lines which name, amount values are present in the set.

```
DELETE
FROM Table1
WHERE (name, amount) in(
    ....
)
```